# Regular Expression to find matches of String series

Tags: regex, string, delimiter

I'm a new bee in regular expression and need help in delimiting string that follows a certain pattern.

My string will be always follow a pattern like ".(0.satQA).(1.SomewhatEnjoyable).(0.satQC).(0.ShorterThanExpected).(0.Q12).(0._1)".

My first search should return (the bold one here) **(0.satQA).(1.SomewhatEnjoyable)**.(0.satQC).(0.ShorterThanExpected).(0.Q12).(0._1)

second as (0.satQA).(1.SomewhatEnjoyable).**(0.satQC).(0.ShorterThanExpected)**.(0.Q12).(0._1)

Third as (0.satQA).(1.SomewhatEnjoyable).(0.satQC).(0.ShorterThanExpected).**(0.Q12).(0._1)**

In short, I need to delimit this into 3 parts (in this case). It should start with "(" and follow with characters (any), must include ").(" in the middle and then end with ")".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex for the pattern you are looking for is `\(.*?\)\.\(.*?\)`

`.*?` is a reluctant greedy quantifier, meaning that will match as it can before the next match in the regex

You also need to escape characters like `.` `)` and `(`

Comment: Thank you Song. your answers works for my requirement. I will test this in different scenarios and let you know in case of any queries or help.